# Identifying the sequence in a recursive function

Tags: python, sequencing

I need to identify the sequence order in the myst(n) function when it is called to then be able to give the output of myst(4).
The function is defined as follow:

```
def myst(n):

    if n > 1:
        myst(n - 1)

        for i in range(n):
            print(n, end='')
        print()


myst(4)
```

```
OUTPUT

22
333
4444
```

But i can't understand why myst(4) gives this output, hence the misunderstanding of the sequence.

Comment: What is the expected output you want to get! Mention that in the question

Comment: What part exactly don't you understand?

Comment: i don't understand why it is myst(2) printed first, then myst(3), and finally myst(4). I initially thought that this function printed nothing ... before running the code that is. This question was an exercice i had, where i needed to guess the output

Comment: Because the output depends whether the print is called before or after the recursive function! Check my answer below!

Answer (score 1):

Basically what is happening is that the function is recursing before it prints. So instead of printing `4444`, then recursing, printing `333`, etc., it recurses to the bottom-most level first, before printing the resuts. That means that the first call to the function that actually completes is the bottom-most one (the one that prints `22`), then after that, the call producing the output `333` completes, until at last, the initial function call completes to print `4444`.

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you are recursing before you print, the call order will be
 `myst(2) -> myst(3) -> myst(4)`

But if you print and then recurse, the call order will change to
`myst(4) -> myst(3) -> myst(2)`, as below.

```
def myst(n):

    if n > 1:

        for i in range(n):
            print(n, end='')
        print()
        myst(n - 1)


myst(4)
#4444
#333
#22
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `myst(x)`, you firstly start to calling `myst(x-1)` and AFTER it ends you continue to `myst(x)`. So you call it to the myst(2) and then start to process another `myst`s. If you want to print it firstly, you should move recursive calling to the bottom:

```
def myst(n):
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(n):
            print(n, end='')
        print()
        myst(n - 1)

myst(4)
```

```
4444
333
22
```